# Get related objects into a single queryset?

Tags: django, django-orm

I have 3 models. `Module`, `Task`, and `Lesson`. `Lesson` is related to `Module` through an FK. Task is connected to Lesson through FK. I am trying to get all the lessons and tasks in a single queryset of a particular module.

```
class Module(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Lesson(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    module = models.ForeignKey('module', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    lesson = models.ForeignKey('lesson', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I want to get all the related Lessons to a module and the tasks related to it in a single queryset.

This is what I have tried

```
module = Module.objects.get(id=57)
lessons = Lesson.objects.filter(module=module)
tasks = Task.objects.filter(lesson__id__in=[lesson.id for lesson in lessons])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I went through the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects) and apparently I don't need to create a separate object that holds lessons and all it tasks because `lessons = Lesson.objects.filter(module=module)`  already has `tasks` which can be accessed with something like this

```
for lesson in lessons:
    print(lesson.task_set.all())
```

or in jinja2 template like this

```
{% for task in lessons.task.all %}
    {{ lesson }}
{% endfor %}
```